# How to add a new custom UIViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I'm a new guy in this field

and i have a problem when i addSubView in AppDelegate

i have a Custom Controller look like this:

```
@interface mainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> 
{
    UITabBarController *myTad;
    UITableView *myTable;
    aModel *myModel
    // ......
}
//Some methods and @property
```

All i want is make a View Controller that gets other Controller also connect to the model.
this is the place work all the things

and in AppDelegate i added in proper way.

```
[window addSubview: myController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES
```

but its just didn't work ?

**The Problem is loadView, the method i overWrite in mainViewController implement not do anythings. It's just go through**

didn't i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push your new view controller onto the stack, like so:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a UINavigationController to control and 'connect' your views. This will allow you to push them properly and navigate back via back button.